# Color code rows of SharePoint 2019 list with multiple pages in classic view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sharepoint

I have a long status list in SharePoint 2019 that has the following CSS for color coding rows:

1. how do I get this to work on all the multiple pages vs just the first page of the list.
2. Can the code be modified to work with a grouped view as well?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/aaa/MSLibrary/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document.ready(function(){
      $Text=$("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('High')");
      $Text.css("background-color", #FFAA99");
      $Text=$("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Medium')");
      $Text.css("background-color", #FFFF99");
      $Text=$("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Low')");
      $Text.css("background-color", #EEFFE6");
    });
</script>
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/aaa/MSLibrary/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document.ready(function(){
      $Text=$("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Not Started')");
      $Text.css("background-color", #F0F0F0");
      $Text=$("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('In Progress')");
      $Text.css("background-color", #D9E5F0");
      $Text=$("td.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2:contains('Completed')");
      $Text.css("background-color", #99CC66");
    });
</script>
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/aaa/MSLibrary/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/aaa/MSLibrary/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    function doCollapseTaskList(){
        $(.ms-commentcollapse-iconouter>img">.each(function(){
            $(this).click();
        });
    }

    $(function(){
         ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
         if(typeofasyncDeltaManager !="undefined")
            asyncDeltaManager.add_endRequest(doCollapseTaskList);
         else doCollapseTaskList();
    },"init.js");
});
</script>
```

Thanks for the help in advance!